# Ubuntu Gnome menu sizes on high res monitor

Tags: gnome, nvidia, resolution, macbook, 14.04

I just updated by macbook with Ubuntu gnome to 14.04. However after updating the gnome menu and button sizes seems to have adapted to the highest possible resolution on the system and I can't figure out how to fix them.

After the system upgrade, the display defaults to 2880x1800 which is way too large for the screen size and results in tiny unreadable pages [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a1kE.png). Instead I would like to use a 1680x1050 resolution, however this results in oversized gnome buttons and menus [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGLRJ.png).

How can I adapt the relative size of the gnome buttons and menu's within a given resolution so that they are normal sized for lower resolutions?

Comment: try changing dpi

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I'm using PC with NVIDIA card.
I seems that it depends, if user is in Administration -group, Gnome will look too big.
But when user have no Admin/sudo -access, Gnome will look and act as normal.